# SQL Server\ORACLE thread safety

Tags: sql

I am new to data base programming.
I am trying to understand how oracle and sql server manage concurrency.

1. Lets say two threads are running. one is updating the row and the other deleting it.

1.1. what does oracle ensure in that case ? could it be that thread2 runs while thread 1 completed only half of the update ?

1.2  what does access ensure in that case ? could it be that thread2 runs while thread 1 completed only half of the update ?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle and Sql Server are enterprise-class servers that guarantee [ACIDic transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). There is no "half update" possible.

For your examples, it is first-in wins: So if a thread deletes a row and then another tries to update it, this will result in an error. If a thread edit's a row and then another deletes it then it will be deleted.